# How can the page size in shiny be adjusted to accommodate more number of plots?

Tags: r, graph, shiny

I have multiple tabs with multiple graphs in some of the tabs. The graphs are implemented as small in size, so the information in graph is difficult to analyze.

I guess shiny automatically resize the graphs in order to adjust with the page size. How to fix this? I am using fluidPage.

Thanks

Comment: did you check out the details here? http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/images.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image size by the `plotOutput()` or `imageOutput()` functions in you `ui.r` file. It has two arguments, `height` and `width` that you can set to determine the image size. You can set the size in  terms of pixels or percentage, e.g. `height = "50%", width = "100px"`

**Edit in response to comments**
I originally had `imageOutput` rather than `plotOuput`, I have corrected that. A plot can be sent to the ui using either `renderImage` or `rednerPlot` but `renderPlot` also has `height` and `width` arguments. If there are really 3 different plots, you could consider making them 3 different plots and with their own `renderPlot` and `plotOutput`. This may give you more flexibility. Regardless the `height` and `width` arguments will help you increase the size of your plot.

Comment: Do you mean I should use renderImage instead of renderPlot? Does it takes one plot as one image? Or multiple plots as one image? Since I have used single id to plot multiple plots in one tab. Example: output$plot1<-renderPlot({ p1<-ggplot(....) p2<-ggplot(...) p3<-ggplot(..) grid.arrange(...)    So here I used one id variable plot1 for three plots.